# Why expo-av is making my android react-native app laggy?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, expo-av

I'm using expo-av to render a list of videos (like Tiktok home screen style), it works fine on IOS but on Android is lagging.
I've tried also `react-native-android-video` but I faced a lot of configuration problems.

Have a look to my code, if you can see something wrong please let me know :

```
<Video
        ref={videoRef}
        nativeID={videoUrl}
        onError={e => console.log(e)}
        isLooping={!pausedMemo}
        isMuted={isMuted}
        accessible={false}
        style={styles.media}
        onLoad={() => setVideoLoaded(true)}
        onLoadStart={() => setVideoLoaded(false)}
        shouldPlay={!pausedMemo}
        useNativeControls={false}
        status={{
          shouldPlay: !pausedMemo,
          isLooping: !pausedMemo,
          isMuted: isMuted,
          pitchCorrectionQuality: PitchCorrectionQuality.High,
          shouldCorrectPitch: true,
          progressUpdateIntervalMillis: 100,
          seekMillisToleranceAfter: 1000,
          seekMillisToleranceBefore: 1000,
        }}
        volume={1}
        pointerEvents="none"
        posterSource={{
          uri: mediaItem.thumbnail_url,
          height: itemHeight,
          width: SIZES.screenWidth,
        }}
        usePoster
        posterStyle={styles.posterStyle}
        onPlaybackStatusUpdate={onProgress}
        progressUpdateIntervalMillis={100}
        resizeMode={ResizeMode.COVER}
        source={{
          uri: videoUrl,
        }}
      />
```

Let me know if you need to see more details.

Comment: Have you tried it in a release build?

Comment: @Abe yes I've tried it in a release build but the same problem

Comment: So, can you please give us more information about your onProgress function and the component? Also, react-native-android-video is not compatible with Expo, unfortunately.